# umask=0 leads to mount error 32

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fstab, umask

Like the title say I have some ext4 that mounts well without umask but are innacessible because of permissions, but leads to error `wrong fs type` when mounted with `umask=0`

I'm on a live USB. So fstab is basically tmpfs, and I can't reboot for any changes to take effect (ro filesystem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all mount options are available for all filesystem types.

In particular, there is no `umask=` mount option for `ext4` or for any fully supported Unix-style filesystems really, because for those filesystem types, the `chown`, `chgrp` and `chmod` commands will work as designed.

If you need to access something that is not allowed for you according to the filesystem's ownership/permission information, then you must be root to do so.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't very clever on this shot. I totally forgot about the root possibility